How to daven for a hostage of unknown status
What should I do if I am unsure of the status of a hostage that I took responsibility to daven for? I don’t know if they are still hostage, freed, or Chas v’shalom not alive anymore.

You can find here an updated list of hostages and their known status. https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/6140595/jewish/Names-of-the-Hostages-in-Gaza-for-Prayer.htm.

We learn from Shabbos that you can dig in a collapsed building until you confirm the occupants are dead or weren't there to begin with so it would make sense you can daven without that level of confirmation too.

This is disputed by the Rishonim. Maharil held that you can't pray for a sick person who is in a different city since he may have died already. See shaarei teshuva https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&st=&pgnum=134

A sick person dying is an observable event, just not by you, who is far away. A hostage in a tunnel is not observable.

I don't understand how a hostage is not observable.

@DoubleAA that's as regards Shabbos, where there are restrictions about what we can daven for. Would Maharil say the same about weekdays?

@Meir it's not obviously about Shabbat in the original sources. Plausibly the whole thing was always about Tefillat Shav

It's not observable because Hamas controls the release of information and the passage of time won't make it revealed.In contrast, the knowledge about the sick person is not restricted and you will find out about it when travelers come from the place.

@ClintEastwood I don't think you are using the word "observable" the way everyone else does.

What kind of kavana should I have when davening for them? I am unsure whether it should be for their neshamos, that they should be freed? bodies released? Should my tefillah just be broadened and vague?

The neshama is indestructible, the bodies are just meat. If you ask for them to be released, unharmed, quickly, it's a tall order,,.so just keep it vague.
